# Newbie: Signing Error while deploying to iOS Device

Tags: ios, ipad, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript and iOS development and trying to do a demo project as mentioned in [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsCT5fpES4Q).

Able to use iOS emulator and make it work Connected new iOS iPad and trying to run against it using **tns run ios device 1** I verified device id using  **tns device ios**

Do I need Apple Developer Paid account to deploy to  iOS device?  Or do i need to setup device first ??? any steps which I am missing?

**Log**:

> Project successfully prepared Build settings from command line:
>       ARCHS = armv7 arm64
>       CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/demo/platforms/ios/build/device
>       SDKROOT = iphoneos9.1
>       SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/demo/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>       VALID_ARCHS = armv7 arm64
>
> === BUILD TARGET demo OF PROJECT demo WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>
> Check dependencies build-debug.xcconfig line 2: Unable to find
>   included file "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig"
>   build-debug.xcconfig line 3: Unable to find included file
>   "../plugins-debug.xcconfig" Code Sign error: No code signing
>   identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and
>   private key pair) were found.
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>           Check dependencies (1 failure) Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65

Here is my **packages.json**:

```
{
        "nativescript": {
                "id": "org.nativescript.demo",
                "tns-ios": {
                        "version": "1.5.0"
                },
                "tns-android": {
                        "version": "1.5.0"
                }
        },
        "dependencies": {
                "tns-core-modules": "1.5.0"
        }
}
```

Comment: You can follow the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nativescript/bjGni8BlWsU).